# Maple software interpolating between two matrices?

Tags: matrix, interpolation, maple

I have two matrices in maple described by:

```
matrix1 := matrix([matrixData]) and matrix2 :=  matrix([matrixDataChanged])
```

Both matrices have the same number of rows and columns, I would like to interpolate the elements in `matrix1` to the elements of `matrix2` as a function of time and store the intermittent results in a variable but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the older matrix constructor, then you can use "evalm" to evaluate expressions.

For example:

```
> A := matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]);
> B := matrix([[10,20],[30,4]]);
> t := 0.25;
> evalm(A*t + B*(1-t));
                                   [7.75     15.50]
                                   [              ]
                                   [23.25    4.00 ]
```

The newer Matrix form should just evaluate.